# Manage Access using $routeChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am Trying to manage access to some urls. when Am not logged in and i try to navigate to the home page it must redirect me to login page. 
This what happens when I navigate to the home page '/' : in my browser the url is #!/login but inside ng-view i get the home view instead of login view.
Navigation to login and signup works fine

```
var app = angular.module('todo', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); 
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "app/partials/home.html",
        requireAuth: true
    })

    .when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "app/partials/login.html",
        requireAuth: false
    })

   .when("/signup", {
        controller: "signupController",
        templateUrl: "app/partials/signup.html",
        requireAuth: false
    })

   .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

}])

 // Manage Access
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'authService', function($rootScope, $location, authService){      
       $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next, current){        
          if((!authService.userInfo.isAuth)&&(next.requireAuth)){
            $location.path('login');
          }

       })
}]);
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of being able to change `$location` during a `$routeChangeStart` event was altered in Angular 1.3.0. This was [fixed in a more recent update](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular.js/commit/a9352c19ce33f0393d6581547c7ea8dfc2a8b78f), so you can either update to the latest version, or use [this workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9607):

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if ((!authService.userInfo.isAuth) && (next.requireAuth)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
            $location.path('/login');
        });
    }
});
```